# Upload data to server on Internet in Android

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to upload to data to a server in background when there are internet and app is not running in the front end.

So I read somewhere this can be achieved by JobService.

I created a simple job service that toasts onStartJob and in the splash screen activity. I called the below code:

```
mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler)
                getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1,
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                        Unigen_Upload_JobScheduler.class.getName()));
        builder.setPeriodic(60000);
        builder.setPersisted(true);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);

        if (mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build()) <= 0) {
            Log.e("Value", "onCreate: Some error while scheduling the job");
        }
```

This runs the first time properly but doesn't run again after 1 minute. I am not sure why this isn't happening?

Also, I had another question will this trigger whenever the WIFI or Mobile is switched ON / Changed?

Do I have to use a broadcast receiver to do the above?

Thanks!

Update:

```
public class Unigen_Upload_JobScheduler extends JobService {

    public Unigen_Upload_JobScheduler() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Executed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.e("Value","+_ what should I do");
        /*
         * True - if your service needs to process
         * the work (on a separate thread).
         * False - if there's no more work to be done for this job.
         */
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum interval for JobScheduler Periodic Job is 15 minutes. Check the reason behind this:

[Why can't an interval be smaller than 15 minutes for periodic jobs?](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-an-interval-be-smaller-than-15-minutes-for-periodic-jobs)

Comment: OK. I will set the periodic job to 15 but will this solve my issue of internet checking in backgroud? Will it run even though I close the app from Background?

Comment: Share your Unigen_Upload_JobScheduler.class code for better understanding

Comment: schedule your job so add this line: mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198095/discussion-between-sanjana-nair-and-sultan-mahmud).

Answer (score 1):

[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)'s minimum periodic interval is 15 minutes or (15 * 60 * 1000) 900000ms. You can look into [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) which is a part of android [jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) for more convenient usage. As for your second question workmanager has convenient methods for scheduling tasks on various scenarios.